# CSS3 Background image height issue

Tags: image, css, background, responsive-design

[image]

Hi Everyone,
Above image is my design. all of them are background images(LHS, RHS, BG, Footer). in all resolutions my design is working properly. The issue is "HEIGHT"... height of the RHS and LHS was being constant in all screen sizes 355px and 692px respectively.

I was scratching my head since two days, with this issue.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="rhs pull-right"> </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <div class="apps">
        <a href="">
     <img src="jquery-mobile/images/apple.png"></a>
        <a href="">
        <img src="jquery-mobile/images/googleplay.png"></a>
        </div>       
        <div class="lhs pull-left"> </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.lhs {
    margin-top:-13%;
    background:url(../images/quote-01.png) no-repeat;
    height:692px;
    width:644px;
    background-size:auto !important;
    }

    .rhs{
    margin-top:10%;
    background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    height:355px;
    width:494px;
    background-size:auto !important;
    }


 @media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {
    .wrapper {width:100%; height:auto;}
.rhs{height:220px !important;background-size:100% !important; min-height:220px !important;}
.lhs {height:320px !important;background-size:100% !important; min-height:320px !important;}
.footer{width:100%;background-size:100% !importantheight:auto; ;}
.apps {width:30% !important;}
}



    @media (max-width:960px){
    body{background-size:cover !important;}
    .rhs{background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat right;
    background-size:100% !important; 
        max-width:100% !important; }
    .lhs{background:url(../images/quote-01.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100% !important; 
    max-width:100% !important; 
    max-height:100% !important;}
    }
```

Hope my question is clear to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never knew that order of media queries also plays main role.. The answer for the above issue is to place `@media(min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {}` under the maximum size `@media (max-width:960px){}`. Everything works perfectly. So, my advice to junior level guys who are struggling with responsive is, "Start your queries from maximum screen size, to avoid stupid issues like these."